# Changing layout gravity to center hides TextView behind tabs

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tabs, android-layoutparams

I am trying to center a `TextView` inside a `NestedScrollView`. This `NestedScrollView` is a part of the tabbed layout's fragment. If `layout_gravity` of the `TextView` is set to default, the `TextView` is shown correctly. But as soon as I change it to `center` the first few lines of the `TextView` are hiding behind the tabs.

Here's the code of a fragment with `NestedScrollView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Fragment_1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frag1_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/buddha_vandana_mar" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And here's the code of tabbed activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PrayerActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BuddhaPoojapathMarathi.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can you please tell me how can I center the `TextView` inside the `NestedScrollView` without losing its contents?

P.S: I've checked the code using `fillViewPort=true`, but it doesn't work.

The default that Android Studio provides after creating Tabbed activity is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BuddhaPoojaMarathi.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I only deleted the TextView and a FLoating Button. Deleting the Floating Button didn't change anything. But after deleting that `TextView` I'm facing the problem as described above.

Comment: Make a `LinearLayout` below the `TabLayout`. Inflate the `NestedScrollView` inside the `LinearLayout` previously made. That is it.

Comment: Didn't work as inteded.